# How to show quicktime videos in succession

Tags: video, quicktime

How do I have two or more quicktime videos to play one after the other, with no action taken by the user? I've seen an example of the technique here:

http://untitled.wiredrive.com//l/p/?presentation=7c79bedbb8b02d2b1da45b033cc20345

I can't seem to boil down their code to the good stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it has been a long time since i programmed in QuickTime; but AFAIR, the C API lets you easily create a movie on memory.  What I'd do is just create a long movie with references to those you want to play.